# ScrollMagic setPin in Safari

Tags: jquery, scroll, click, fixed, scrollmagic

I have layout like this **[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e3daqyjh/6/)**. and I have to stick on this layout only.

Onclick of section4 button the section `.setpin` gets activated. And page jumps and reaches 50% up. It should not Jump.

This is happening only in Safari.

```
$('.next2').click(function(){
    var s4 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ 
      triggerElement:'#section4',
      triggerHook:0,
      duration:'150%',
      offset:0
    })
    .setPin('#section4')
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

**Note:** Please check fiddle demo in safari. Because it works fine in chrome and mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution.

```
var s4 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ 
  triggerElement:'#section4',
  triggerHook:0,
  duration:'150%',
  offset:0
})
.addTo(controller);
```

Write this outside the click event event without setPin(). And make another scrollMagic object inside click event event.

```
$('.next2').click(function(){
var s4_sub = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement:'#section9',
    triggerHook:0,
    duration:'100%',
    offset:0
})
.addTo(controller)
.on('enter', function(event){
    var y=$("body").scrollTop();
    s4.setPin('#section4');
    $("body").scrollTop(y); 
});
});
```

This is final solution.

```
var y=$("body").scrollTop();
$("body").scrollTop(y);
```

It will prevent scroll to going up.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/e3daqyjh/7/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `transform: translate3D(0,0,0);` to fixed div.